# SQL - Set field value based on count of previous rows values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following table structure in Microsoft SQL:

```
ID  Name    Number
1   John    
2   John    
3   John    
4   Mark    
5   Mark    
6   Anne    
7   Anne    
8   Luke    
9   Rachael 
10  Rachael
```

I am looking to set the 'Number' field to the number of times the 'Name' field has appeared previously, using SQL.

Desired output as follows:

```
ID  Name    Number
1   John    1
2   John    2
3   John    3
4   Mark    1
5   Mark    2
6   Anne    1
7   Anne    2
8   Luke    1
9   Rachael 1
10  Rachael 2
```

The table is ordered by 'Name', so there is no worry of 'John' appearing under ID 11 again, using my example.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure if I can do this with a simple SELECT statement, or whether I will need an UPDATE statement, or something more advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function within SQL Server to partition each group (by their `Name` property) and output the individual row in each partition :

```
  SELECT ID, 
         Name, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID) AS Number
    FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ID
```

You can see what your data looks like prior to the query :

[image]

and then after it is executed :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name 
                           ORDER BY ID) AS Number
FROM mytable
```

There is no need to add a field for this, as the value can be easily calculated using window functions.

Answer (score 0):

If your system doesnt support OVER PARTITION, you can use following code:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name, 
 (
    SELECT
        SUM(counterTable.nameCount)
    FROM 
            mytable innerTable
            JOIN (SELECT 1 as nameCount) as counterTable
   WHERE
            innerTable.ID <= outerTable.ID
            AND outerTable.Name = innerTable.Name
        ) AS cumulative_sum
FROM 
    mytable outerTable
ORDER BY outerTable.ID
```

Following CREATE TABLE statement I used and then filled in your data:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `ID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);
```

This should work with DBS not supporting OVER PARTITION like MySQL, Maria, ...

Comment: This is nice and all but the question is clearly tagged with sql server.